# How can I call a .NET MVC action on tab/browser close?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery-events

As a part of my MVC web application, I need to call a controller method when a browser or a browser tab is closed.  I am using the Javascript `onbeforeunload` event for calling the method.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            navigator.sendBeacon("/ABC/RemoveSession");
        }
```

If there are some changes that have been made in the form and if the user tries to exit, i am displaying a confirmation window using the below code

```
        function preventNavigation(message) {
            var confirmOnPageExit = function (e) {
                // If we haven't been passed the event get the window.event
                e = e || window.event;
                // For IE6-8 and Firefox prior to version 4
                if (e) {
                    e.returnValue = message;
                }
                // For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
                return message;
            };

            window.onbeforeunload = confirmOnPageExit
        }

$("#myform :input").change(function () {

       preventNavigation("You have not saved the form. Any changes will be lost if you leave this page.");
           
        });
```

If there are no changes in the form and the tab is closed, the code works fine and the Controller method is called successfully. However, if the form has changed, user is presented with a confirmation message popup on trying to close the form. On clicking the "Leave" button, the tab is closed but controller method is not getting called.

I doubt if this is something that can be done with `onbeforeunload` event. If anyone has ever faced such a problem or know any better way to achieve this, please do let me know.

Comment: Can you trigger the same event by sending a POST request?

Comment: @LajosArpad XHR POST requests aren't guaranteed to finish sending unlike Beacon requests

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary the reason behind my question is that we need to know whether the problem is that unbeforeunload is not finalized or, the problem might be with the request itself. So it makes sense to test sending a POST request and see whether it works consistently. If so, then a solution is needed for the unreliability of requests being sent at unbeforeunload. If not, then the request needs to be fixed first and only then can we evaluate the problem of unbeforeunload. So, the idea is to separately test the possible problems and see what the problems are exactly before we solve it.

Answer (score 0):

onbeforeunload seems to be quite unreliable event for determining if the user is finished with the page. MSDN even warns against it, and recomends visibilitychange event on document (instead window object you use for onbeforeunload).

Any interaction with the page according to MSDN could stop it from fireing. Please try:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function logData() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    navigator.sendBeacon('/ABC/RemoveSession');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Navigator.sendBeacon()` is meant to be used with the `visibilitychange` event, *not* `onbeforeunload`.**

[MDN states:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

> **Avoid unload and beforeunload**
>
> In the past, many websites have used the unload or beforeunload events to send analytics at the end of a session. However, this is **extremely unreliable**. **In many situations**, especially on mobile, **the browser will not fire the unload, beforeunload, or pagehide events**. For example, these events will not fire in the following situations:
>
> 1. The user loads the page and interacts with it.
> 2. When they are finished, they switch to a different app, instead of closing the tab.
> 3. Later, they close the browser app using the phone's app manager.
>
> ...

Replace:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    navigator.sendBeacon("/ABC/RemoveSession");
}
```

With:

```js
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    navigator.sendBeacon("/ABC/RemoveSession");
  }
});
```